# The use of "work with" vs. "work at/on"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrasal-verbs

In one of my previous questions, Tiercelet left a *[comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30389/a-fantastic-excerpt-for-learning-the-usage-of-prepositions#tab-top)*:

> It's a pleasure to **work with** such well-thought-out and nuanced
>   questions!

It seems *work with* has a similar meaning to *work on* or *work at* here.

However, I have consulted multiple dictionaries. They don't have examples for *work with*. Could *work on* or *work at* be used here instead?

User3169 provided a source below I had failed to look up. [The TheFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+with) offers several examples:

> Let me **work with** him for a while. I'll convince him.
>
> I want to **work with** this engine and see if I can get it started.

But I would have worded them this way:

> Let me **work on** him for a while. I'll convince him. (Or simply, let me **work** (transitive) him for a while. )
>
> I want to **work at/on** this engine and see if I can get it started.

Any different connotations implied?

Answer (score 3):

*Work with X* does not have to be a phrasal verb, it can mean literally "to work with X" - e.g. "I worked with John at the factory."

Phrasally, it means to A) to use X, typically toward completing a task or project, B) rely on X for assistance with or make sure X completes a task or project.

*Work on/at X* does not have to be a phrasal verb, it can mean literally what it says - "John and I worked on the loading dock today" or "John and I worked at the factory today."

Phrasally, both *work on X* and *work at X* mean to to do things over time to improve X or move X towards completion.  *Work at X* is tends to be used when X is something abstract without a defined end goal.

The difference in meanings usually depends on whether X is a person or not.

> I worked with John today.  (John and I worked together today)
>
> I worked with the new machine today.  (I used the new machine today)
>
> I worked on the roof today (I was on top of the roof - but can also mean the roof was a project and you moved forward with completing it)
>
> I worked on the project today (I tried to move forward on the project, I was not standing on an object known as "project")
>
> I worked at the jail today (I was at the jail, working while there)
>
> I worked at improving our processes today.  (We don't have a definite plan for improving our processes, but we want to, and I did some things that can help.)

Comment: Could you address the specific examples in my Q rather than provide your own? I'd like to know if *work on/at* could deliver a different connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Let take it with your examples

> Let me **work with** him for a while. I'll convince him.

Here it means that you want to work with him on some project. In between you will try to convince him on project or something else.

> Let me **work on** him for a while. I'll convince him.

Here it means that you want to try something or talk to him on a project which you want him to get convinced on.