# What does 'work with' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does 'work with' mean?

> Penguins are not the only animals that have used tablet computers. At Zoo Atlanta, in the American state of Georgia, orangutans, gorillas, and sun bears have also **worked with** the technology.

[Animals Like Video Games, Too](https://www.google.com/amp/s/learningenglish.voanews.com/amp/3980345.html)

Comment: Check this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98180/the-use-of-work-with-vs-work-at-on)

Answer (score 2):

It means that orangutans, gorillas, and sun bears have used tablet computers.

The sense of *work* is *to use [as a tool to do something].*

In the same way as *A carpenter works with hammers, nails, and wood.*

It is probably confusing to you because the pair of words *work with* often has other meanings, such as *work together with,* as in *Mary works [together] with her sister.*

It can also mean that two or more things match well or accomplish something well in combination:

> *The black boots really work with the red dress.*
>   *Yeast works with sugar to make bread dough rise.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sentence examples, "with" is used when you are referring to the connection as in I worked with the ABC company, meaning I and abc company worked together.