# Meaning of "work with shame"

Tags: meaning

> Sanderson has used extensive reading and clinical experience to
>   develop a resource that will help counsellors, and I suspect their
>   clients, to **work with shame**, rather than avoiding it.

From *[Counselling skills for working with shame - One In Four UK](https://www.oneinfour.org.uk/counselling-skills-for-working-with-shame/)*

What does "work with" mean here?

I have checked this thread: *[The use of "work with" vs. "work at/on"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98180/the-use-of-work-with-vs-work-at-on)*

> Phrasally, it means to (A) use X, typically toward completing a task
>   or project, or (B) rely on X for assistance with or make sure X completes
>   a task or project.

But here I think shame is not a tool and not something that a therapist relies on for assistance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This usage is a common form in psychiatric, self-help, and business writing.

Here **work with** means *engage*, and is in contrast to **avoiding [shame]** -- the writer is saying that shame should be consciously engaged, not avoided.  In a specialist book for counsellors, "shame" is linguistically almost a material, a type of substance, and usage is just like "Working with wood".

It is very close in usage to **work with [a force]**, in contrast to **work against [a force]**.

There is a third meaning: **work with [abstract noun]** -- such as "work with pride / speed / anger" -- which has the same construction but an adverbial meaning.  The context -- a specialist manual for counsellors -- tells us this isn't what's meant in your case, but it can be ambiguous.  "Working with disability" could mean "Having a job if you have a disability" (adverbial meaning) and it can equally mean "Doing Social Work with clients who have disabilities" (as material).

Comment: So "work with" here connotes two things.  One is treating shame as a material. The other is working with something instead of working against something. Does "work with" always have the second connotation?  Because when you say "work with wood", I think it is neutral.

Comment: It means shame as "material", but with a positive connotation.  "Work with wood" is normally completely neutral, as you say.

Comment: "Work with" has a connotation closer to "working with a material"- shaping or altering it. Like an artist **works with oils"**. More this,than working g with/against it.

Answer (score 5):

You can better understand the usage of the word "with" in your context if, instead of saying "to work with shame," you say "to deal with shame" or "to learn how to live with shame." "[Deal with](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deal%20with)" is a phrase that means "to do something about a person or thing that causes a problem or difficult situation."

So, you do not need to think about "with" as a separate word.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. I wish I could accept two answers.  Thanks for your help.  "Deal with" makes things easier to understand. .